# Can't find referenced method 'void sort(java.util.Comparator)' in library class java.util.ArrayList

Tags: java, android, proguard, android-proguard

I've configured my project for pro-guard which was working fine for a long while and now all of a sudden I'm getting this error on production.

```
Warning:com.company.game.objects.ui.popups.MPSearch$2$1: can't find referenced method 'void sort(java.util.Comparator)' in library class java.util.ArrayList
```

I'm creating a comparator in my class like such:

```
//Within: (com.company.game.objects.ui.popups;)
compareStrings = new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                return o1.compareTo(o2);
            }
        };

 //A little later.
 searchResults.sort(compareStrings);
```

I've tried setting a flag in pro-guard to ignore all the classes involved (MPSearch, Java.Utils.**)

But then I get crashes that are undiagnosable.

Comment: You should use `Collections.sort(searchResults, compareStrings);`. (`Collection.sort` became available in Java 8 and Java 8 is not supported on Android.)

Comment: Is there anyway to tell Android studio not to use Java 8 stuff?

Comment: Are you sure Android studio allows you to use Java 8 stuff?